# awk: Print three lines from a group of lines

Tags: perl, awk

I have a text file with groups of line, from that I need only first three lines from each group.

File:

```
test1|pass
test1|pass
test1|pass
test1|pass
test1|pass
test2|fail
test2|fail
test2|fail
test2|fail
test3|pass
test3|pass
test3|pass
test3|pass
```

Expected Output:

```
test1|pass
test1|pass
test1|pass
test2|fail
test2|fail
test2|fail
test3|pass
test3|pass
test3|pass
```

What I have tried so far:

```
BEGIN {
        FS = "|"
}
        $1==x {
        if (NR % 5 <= 3) {
                print $0
        }
        next
}
{
        x=$1
        print $0
}

END {
        printf "\n"
}
```

Comment: @Krishna His awk script is in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this fairly concisely like this:

```
awk -F'|' '++a[$1] <= 3' infile
```

Output:

```
test1|pass
test1|pass
test1|pass
test2|fail
test2|fail
test2|fail
test3|pass
test3|pass
test3|pass
```

*Explanation*

`a` is an associative array. We use the first element of each line (`$1`) as a key into `a` and increment its value. This value is then compared to `3` and if the comparison is true, the default block is executed (`{print $0}`).

Comment: It worked fine, could you please explain how this works, when you have time.

Comment: You could also use `$0` as the array key to ensure you have at most 3 of any line.

Comment: @glennjackman: Yes, but that would depend on what other requirements the OP has, which isn't clear as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN {
        FS = "|"
}
        $1==x && count <= 3 {
        print;
        count++;
        }
        next
}
{
        x=$1;
        print;
        count=1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other way using awk

```
awk '{a[$1]+=1}END{ for (b in a) {for(i=1; i<=3; i++) print b} }'  temp.txt | sort
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in ascending order like you have shown in your Question, then you can have this perl code.

```
#!/usr/perl/bin -w

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file_name = "file.txt";
my $new_file = "new_file.txt";
open(FH, "<".$file) or die "Could not open $file";
open (NFH, ">$new_file") or die "Could not open $new_file";

my @content = <FH>;

my $old_line = "";
my $count = 0;
foreach my $line (@content) {

    if( ($old_line ne $line) || ($count < 3) ) {
        print NFH $line;
    }

    print NFH "$first $second $third";
}

close NFH;
close FH;
```

**OR**

If your data is not in order, then you can use this Perl code:

```
#!/usr/perl/bin -w
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file_name = "file.txt";
my $new_file = "new_file.txt";
open(FH, "<".$file) or die "Could not open $file";
open (NFH, ">$new_file") or die "Could not open $new_file";

my @content = <FH>;

my %hash = map($_ => 1) @content;
my $count = 0;
foreach my $key (keys(%hash)) {
    while($count < 3) {
    print NFH $key;
    $count++;
    }
}

close NFH;
close FH;
```